# Carthage update failing with error message SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, carthage

Currently I'm on xcode version 10.1 and swift version 4.2. I'm using CryptoSwift lib and when I tried `carthage update` it is failing to build with error message `SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2`.

I'm trying solve the problem:

1. ```
   if swift_verion > 4.2 {
     //Download x version
   }else {
     //Download y version
   }
   ```
2. Or there any way to compile build with available version only?

```
Build settings from command line:

    CARTHAGE = YES
    CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE = NO
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = 
    CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED = NO
    GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS = NO
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO
    SDKROOT = iphoneos12.1
    SKIP_INSTALL = YES
    STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT = NO
    TOOLCHAINS = com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_4_2

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
Build system information
error: SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'CryptoSwift')
```

Comment: It looks like CryptoSwift has been updated to Swift 5. You will need to update your Xcode to 10.2 for Swift 5 support.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the CryptoSwift lib was updated to Swift 5 using Xcode 10.2 in their latest release (1.0.0). You are getting this error because you need to update your Xcode Version and migrate your project to Swift 5, if you want to point to this new version. Projects using Swift 5 can only be built with Xcode 10.2.

Note that Apple is dropping support for Swift 3 pretty soon, and it is probably a good idea to upgrade pretty soon. Managing dependencies during migrations can be a pain because you have no control over when other development teams will switch over.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using the following in my `Cartfile`:

```
github "krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift" "swift42"
```

This uses the Swift 4.2 branch of CryptoSwift and you won't have to convert your project.